# Underscore.js get value of key object in array of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

i have to get the value of wave1 and wave2 from array by using underscore.js

```
array =[{"id":1,"name":"Monoprix", "pdv":16,"graph":[{"wave1":22,"wave2":11}]} ;
```

i try

```
 $scope.wave1 =array.graph.wave1 ;
   console.log($scope.wave1) ;
```

console log = Unidentified

can you help me !

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: `array` is an array.  It doesn't have a `graph` property.  Its first element does, however.

Answer (score 0):

your code is wrong, you miss ] after element list.

your array :

```
var array =[{"id":1,"name":"Monoprix", "pdv":16,"graph":[{"wave1":22,"wave2":11}]}];
```

and to get some data you must first select array index, like this:

```
array[0].graph
```